# Accessing method in main activity from another class

Tags: java, android

How do I access the method myMethod from another class?

```
public class controller extends Activity 
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    int myMethod() {int id = 0; return id;} //arbitrary example, may also be static?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in your `controller` `Activity` to the other class, the way you would with any other object in Java. Just be careful not to hold onto an `Activity` in places that might cause garbage collection issues (e.g., a service, a static data member, a custom `Application` object).

Comment: @Dirk Bruere: Newcomers to Java should learn Java before learning Android.

Comment: The real problem is that I cannot set a listview adapter in another class on a listview in main. Tried passing context etc and it doesn;t work.

Comment: Can you fill in the??? pls 
public class BlinkAPI
{
static SeekBar volSliderSB;
static ArrayAdapter<String> radioTitleAdapter;
public BlinkAPI( Context ctx)
 {
  BlinkAPI.mContext = ctx;
  volSliderSB = (SeekBar )((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.SeekBarVolume);
  radioTitleAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)????
 }
}

Comment: @Dirk Bruere: Call `findViewById()` to get your `ListView`, then call `getAdapter()` on the `ListView`. Then delete the entire `BlinkAPI` class and move all of its logic into the `Activity` or `Fragment` where it belongs.

Comment: I seem to have resolved the problem by collecting all the data arrays into one Data class, along with the methods to create and attach adapters to listviews. This is instantiated in main and has the context passed to it